# Visibility of the `edit` link

Tags: feature-request

It sometimes occurs to me that `text-decoration: none` makes the **edit** link difficult for some visitors hard to identify. On more than one occasion, a comment pointing out the link has resulted in a better question.

As I type: [Do the sentences have the same meaning?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/101805/37009)

<sub>(**EDIT:** Not an exemplary outcome, but proof of concept at least.)</sub>

Is it fair to assume that there are many unreported instances of this event? That is to say, I assume that there are many instances in which the poster, without prompting, fails to expand or edit her question (in response to a comment, for instance) only because she doesn't recognize the grey links below her answer.

Obviously, this is more likely to be a problem for those at the very beginning of their study. Would not an obvious and unmistakeably buttonish element increase the number of edits by questioners?

Comment: Well, on the other sites that I frequent, askers tend to have a problem with finding out how to edit their post. I don't think it's because of `text-decoration` or lack thereof, but because generally there are so many things to click in SE UI that makes it confusing for newer users of the system. ELL's askers being nonnative English speakers, I guess they'd have a bigger problem finding out how to edit. On [chemistry.SE], whenever we ask the OP to edit their post, we leave an `[edit]` in our comment so they click on it. [ . . . ]

Comment: [ . . . ] Even then, when people aren't being cooperative, they add a couple of odd-sounding comments in reply with *pls halp need till tomorrow exam* in the end. All that aside, I value this request, but I wonder what elegant way there would be to make "edit" more visible without changing the UI much.

Comment: @DEAD Elegant schmelegant. That can't really be a consideration?! Don't you think a big button-shaped object <blink>ing **EDIT** would make things easier, especially for beginners? Seems obvious to me. Unless we can't violate a design requirement in the code deployed across SE, or something.

Comment: We have to take UX into account, which roughly translates to elegance. Other than that, I fully support a blinking marquee with alternating colors that flies all over the page like that Microsoft logo screensaver on Windows.

Comment: **CATCH ME for BONUS PLAYZ**

Comment: <<< ---- ^^^^ HOOT ^^^^  <<<--- visualize a scrolling comment <<<----